# Jquery nav bar, how to customize the look and feel

Tags: jquery-mobile, navbar

Is there anyway to make the nav bar look like this?
Do you know a plugin maybe? the jqm nav bar is really ugly....
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your navbar with custom icons and such. Here's the docs: 
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

As for other options, you can change the color themes and such with jQuery Mobile Themeroller: http://www.jquerymobile.com/themeroller